# Java Scanner Within Another Method

Tags: java

I am working on a lab for one of my classes therefore I am looking more for an explanation than for actual code.

For part of this assignment I need to read in numbers from the user until control-d is pressed. I have a while loop in a method and I am passing the scanner into the method as well, here is my main method:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Length:");
    int length = 0;

    if(scan.hasNextInt()){
        length = scan.nextInt();
    }

    if(length<0 || length>100){
        System.out.println("Length is not of the proper size");
        scan.close();
        return;
    }

    Double[] a1 = new Double[length];
    Double[] a2 = new Double[length];
    fillWithZeros(a1);
    fillWithZeros(a2);

    System.out.println("Enter the numbers to be multiplied:");

    a1 = fillWithValues(a1,scan);
    a2 = fillWithValues(a2,scan);
    double total = calculateTotal(a1,a2);
    printVector(a1,"a1");
    printVector(a2,"a2");
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    scan.close();
```

Then here is my fillWithValues method:

```
public static Double[] fillWithValues(Double[] array, Scanner scan) {
    int numberOfElements = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextDouble()){
        if(numberOfElements<array.length){
            array[numberOfElements] = scan.nextDouble();
            numberOfElements++;
        }else{
            return array;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

The issue I am having is that when I press Control-D it doesn't end the input stream like it should, but I have the code above in main it would end the input stream, so could someone explain why I am having this issue?

I would just declare the scanner as a global variable but I am not allowed to use global variables for this assignment.

Comment: If you have the **exact** code as in your separate method also in your main method of the other code variant, it should behave the same. Please post the complete code of both variants, the working one and the non working one (see also [mcve]).

Comment: i have edited it showing all of my code for the main and then the method that isn't working. If i take the code in the fillWithValues method and put it in main and change the array name to a1, or a2 instead of array it works just fine

Comment: So, you are replacing the **two** `fillWithValues()` calls with **one** code block from that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, you are using

```
a1 = fillWithValues(a1,scan);
a2 = fillWithValues(a2,scan);
```

where `fillWithValues()` essentially does

```
while(scan.hasNextDouble()){
   ...
}
```

That means, if the scanner observes the EOF character (`CTRL-D` in case of Unix), `scan.hasNextDouble()` will return `false` and the method will terminate - however, your program immediately calls the method again where the scanner will wait for the next double (if you press `CTRL-D` again the program should finally terminate in this case also).

If you replace the **two** method calls with **one** invocation of the loop, the programm will just resume after the (first any only) loop and terminate.

To solve that, you can let the method return a `boolean` instead of the array (you do not need to return and re-assign the array as return value since you are already modifying the array elements of the array you are passing as parameter):

```
public static boolean fillWithValues(Double[] array, Scanner scan) {
    int numberOfElements = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextDouble()){
        if(numberOfElements<array.length){
            array[numberOfElements] = scan.nextDouble();
            numberOfElements++;
        }else{
            return true;  // all elements read
        }
    }
    return false;   // input aborted
}
```

The calling code can then decide whether to terminate or to continue:

```
if (fillWithValues(a1,scan) == true) {
    fillWithValues(a2,scan);  // could also check the return value again if required
}
```

BTW, use `static` methods only when absolutely required - there is no need here. You should take that as an excercise to remove the `static` method, once your overall logic works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the behaviour of `hasNextDouble()`, from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble%28%29):

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
>   interpreted as a double value using the `nextDouble()` method. The
>   scanner does not advance past any input.

So first off, **Ctrl-D** by itself will never be read or scrutinized unless you complete a token by pressing enter. When you do this `fillWithValues()` will quit because `hasNextDouble()` returns false for any non-double input (not just **Ctrl-D**). Secondly, because scanner does not advance past any input, the following call to `fillWithValues()` begins and ends on the same non-double input and won't read more doubles as you expect. At the very least you need to pass the token that causes the first call to stop (and if it needs to be **Ctrl-D** specifically check for that).